# Java Declare a variable and then initialize it.?

Tags: java

```
public class TestVariableDeclaration{
    int j;  // ERROR
    j=45;   // ERROR

    static{
        int k;
        k=24;

    }

    {

        int l;
        l=25;
    }

    void local(){
        int loc;
        loc=55;
    }

}
```

1. In the above why can't I declare a variable "j" and then initialize directly under a class
2. I can declare and then initialize in the same manner under a Method,Static/Instance initialization block?
3. What makes the difference, I am aware about the fact that Java does not support Declaring and then initializing a instance variable. What's the reason behind that??

Comment: The compiler isn't smart enough

Comment: `int j=45;` you can initialize while declaring

Comment: May i know the reason why declaration and then initialization of the variable is not possible??

Comment: because at the possion where you wrote `j=45;` only declarations are allowed but not statements.

Answer (score 2):

1. you can declare on class level with int j = 45; as mentioned by  Subhrajyoti Majumder
2. k is in a special function/method,  call it the static initializer. it is executed when class is loaded. k is only known inside this method
3. l is in a special method which is executed on class instantiation. l is only known in this method.

This is very basic java stuff.

(edit:typos)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a variable before declaring it under normal circumstances. So

```
j=45;
```

at the top will fail since `j` hasn't been declared yet.

Unless I am not getting your question, this is very much possible with:

```
class SomeClass {
    int j; // declare it
    {
        j=45; // initialize it
    }
}
```

OR even more concise:

```
class SomeClass {
    int j = 45; // declare and initialize
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you simply initialize and declare it together like this -> `int j=45;`? It works that way for me..